# cat from file.csv with grep data

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cat

I have data in `file.csv`:

```
(...)
0000046;0000046;04688;29;1;52.1683;20.5567
0000046;0000046;04688;2A;1;52.1818;20.5639
0000046;0000046;04688;3;1;52.1785;20.5629
0000046;0000046;04688;4;1;52.1815;20.5638
0000046;0000046;04688;5;;52.1779;20.5635
0000046;0000046;04688;6;1;52.1813;20.5636
0000046;0000046;04688;7;;52.1777;20.5634
0000046;0000046;04688;8;;52.1810;20.5635
0000046;0000046;04688;9;1;52.1775;20.5631
0000046;0000046;05027;2;;52.1908;20.5660
0000046;0000046;05027;4;1;52.1907;20.5649
0000046;0000046;05527;1;1;52.1824;20.5636
(...)
```

I need to extract lines where the third field matches a given value.  I tried

```
cat file.csv |grep 05027
```

Unfortunately, this matches any line containing `05027` anywhere.  How can I restrict to matching only on the third field?

Comment: for the sample input shown, the command you tried should have worked... can you copy paste the output you got?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you don't need the `cat` for grep, you can just `grep pattern file`

awk is easier to handle column based data input.

What you can try is:

```
awk -F';' '$3=="05027"' file
```

Comment: @A.M.D: OP hasn't yet earned the [privilege to upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).